# A question related to "Locally Sidorenko" type problem

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory

Let $F$ be a bipartite graph and $\delta_F=\delta(F)$ be a constant. Let $p\geq 0$ be a given constant.

Let $W$ be a graphon with $\int W=p$ and for any $A,B\subseteq \left[0,1\right]$ with $|A|,|B|\geq\delta_F$, $\int_{A\times B} W\geq (1-\delta_F)p|A||B|$. Moreover, for any $C\subseteq\left[0,1\right]$ and $|C|\leq\delta_F^{-1}$, $\int_{\left[0,1\right]\times C}W\geq (1-\delta_F)p|C|$. Could these condition implies that $t(F,W)\geq\delta_F\cdot t(F,\delta_F\cdot p)$ for some $\delta_F\geq 0$?

Background: In the condition that $\delta_F=\delta(F,p)$, Lovasz's work implies it: "Subgraph densities in signed graphons and the local Simonovits–Sidorenko conjecture", https://arxiv.org/pdf/1004.3026.pdf, Corollary 3.5 by taking $\varepsilon=o(p^l)$. Now get rid of the condition $\delta_F$ is related to $p$, could we prove it into a linear approximate result $t(F,W)\geq\delta_F \cdot t(F,\delta_F\cdot p)$?

*Corollary 3.5 Let $F$ be a bipartite graph with $n$ nodes and $m$ edges, and let $G$ be a graph with $N$ nodes and $M=p\left(\begin{array}{c}N \\ 2\end{array}\right)$ edges. Let $\varepsilon>0$. Assume that
$$
\left|e_G(S, T)-p\right| S|\cdot| T|| \leq\left(2^{-8 m} p-\varepsilon\right) N^2
$$
for all $S, T \subseteq V(G)$, and
$$
e_G(S, T) \leq 2 p|S| \cdot|T|
$$
for all $S, T \subseteq V(G)$ with $|S|,|T| \geq 2^{-4 m^2 / \varepsilon^2} N$. Then
$$
t(F, G) \geq p^l-\varepsilon .
$$*

Comment: (a) your lower bound on $\int_{A \times B} W$ appears to be incorrectly normalized (do you mean $(1-\delta_F) p |A| |B|$?).  (b) I cannot locate an assertion in Lovasz's paper that resembles what you are claiming here (and cannot parse what the intended statement is supposed to be).  Can you provide a more precise statement (with references) of the relevant result of Lovasz (and also link to the paper, and also define your terms more precisely?).

Comment: @TerryTao 
  Thanks for your comment! (a)Thanks for your correction, I'm sorry to forget to write |A||B|.   (b)It is in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1004.3026.pdf Corollary 3.5, taking the $\varepsilon$ no more than $o(p^l)$.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question correctly, you are asking if there is a sparse graph counting lemma assuming only that the graphon is within $o(p)$ to the density $p$ in cut norm; the Lovasz result corresponds to the stronger assumption where the cut norm is assumed to be sufficiently small depending on $p$.  I believe the following construction furnishes a counterexample to this claim.

Let $N$ be a large natural number (one can take it to be prime if desired, though it isn't too important), and let $E$ be a random symmetric subset of ${\bf Z}/N{\bf Z} \backslash \{0\}$ of expected cardinality $N^{0.49}$ (any exponent slightly less than $1/2$ would do here).  Let $E' := E \backslash (E+E)$.  Standard first moment estimates (see e.g., Chapter 1 of my book with Van Vu) show that with high probability, $E'$ is most of $E$; indeed, $|E \backslash E'| \ll N^{-0.02} |E|$ with high probability.  Now let $G$ be the Cayley graph of $E'$ on ${\bf Z}/N{\bf Z}$.  By construction, $E'$ is symmetric and sum-free, hence $G$ is triangle free, and the density $p = |E'|/(N-1)$ of this graph is $p \asymp N^{-0.51}$.  In particular, the density of triangles in this graph is significantly below the random triangle density count of $p^3$.

With high probability, all of the non-trivial Fourier coefficients of $E$ are small (of size $o(p)$); in fact one obtains a power savings in $N$. The same is therefore true of $E'$, since $E \backslash E'$ has cardinality $o(pN)$. From this and a standard application of Plancherel's theorem, we see that the number of edges in $G$ between two subsets $A,B$ of ${\bf Z}/N{\bf Z}$ is $p |A| |B| + o(p)$.  So the graphon associated to $G$ will obey your hypothesis (in fact $\delta_F$ can be taken to be some negative power of $N$), yet the count of triangles is too small.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, in hypothesis, I want it be a dense graph, but not sparse. It means that for any given $p\geq 0$, and for any graphon $W$ with density $p$, if it satisfy the hypothesis(edge density between any two linear-order subset is close to $p$, but the difference between it and $p$ is allowed to be $\Theta p$), could we count linear number (the linear coefficient should not depends on $p$) of $F$ as in the quasirandom graph? Thanks!

Comment: As it seems you do not want the constant $\delta_F$ to depend on $p$, the claim in your question would cover both dense and sparse graphs, and I believe the construction in my answer provides a negative answer to your question (specialising to the case where $p$ is a small power of $N$).  If this is not the case, you should clarify the order of quantifiers in your question.

Comment: On closer inspection, though, I see that you want to restrict $F$ to be bipartite, which excludes the construction in my answer (in which $F$ is a triangle).  In which case no counterexample is known, since no counterexample to the full Sidorenko conjecture is known.  However, the above construction does show that any positive answer would have to use the bipartite hypothesis in an essential way.

Comment: I'm very sorry that my previous expression caused misunderstanding. I have edited it. Do you think it can be proved in the condition that it is a dense graph with $p$ is the edge density? Thank you!

Comment: Moreover, adding a hypothesis that for any $C\subseteq\left[0,1\right]$ and $|C|\leq\delta_F^{-1}$, $\int_{\left[0,1\right]\times C}W\geq (1-\delta_F)p|C|$ and this leads to a stronger condition than the cut norm. Could this question be proved having update the question to now? Sincerely thank you for your time!